# Fedora 31 and Snapd issue

Tags: fedora, snap

I'm trying to use snapd on Fedora31, but unsucessfull.. 
Step 1 - Installation:

```
[otaviolarrosa@localhost ~]$ sudo dnf install snapd
Last metadata expiration check: 0:46:14 ago on Sat 04 Jan 2020 04:11:31 PM -03.
Dependencies resolved.
========================================================================================================================
 Package                  Architecture              Version                            Repository                  Size
========================================================================================================================
Installing:
 snapd                    x86_64                    2.42.2-1.fc31                      updates                     16 M

Transaction Summary
========================================================================================================================
Install  1 Package

Total download size: 16 M
Installed size: 60 M
Is this ok [y/N]: Y
Downloading Packages:
snapd-2.42.2-1.fc31.x86_64.rpm                                                                                                           1.4 MB/s |  16 MB     00:11    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Total                                                                                                                                    1.3 MB/s |  16 MB     00:12     
Running transaction check
Transaction check succeeded.
Running transaction test
Transaction test succeeded.
Running transaction
  Preparing        :                                                                                                                                                 1/1 
  Installing       : snapd-2.42.2-1.fc31.x86_64                                                                                                                      1/1 
  Running scriptlet: snapd-2.42.2-1.fc31.x86_64                                                                                                                      1/1 
Created symlink /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/snapd.socket → /usr/lib/systemd/system/snapd.socket.
Created symlink /etc/systemd/user/sockets.target.wants/snapd.session-agent.socket → /usr/lib/systemd/user/snapd.session-agent.socket.

  Verifying        : snapd-2.42.2-1.fc31.x86_64                                                                                                                      1/1 

Installed:
  snapd-2.42.2-1.fc31.x86_64                                                                                                                                             

Complete!
```

Step 2 - See the version of snapd

```
[otaviolarrosa@localhost ~]$ snap version
snap    2.42.2-1.fc31
snapd   2.42.2-1.fc31
series  16
fedora  31
kernel  5.3.7-301.fc31.x86_64
```

Step 3 - Try to install a package

```
[otaviolarrosa@localhost ~]$ sudo snap install hello-world
error: system does not fully support snapd: cannot mount squashfs image using "squashfs": mount:
       /tmp/sanity-mountpoint-803995619: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/loop0,
       missing codepage or helper program, or other error.
```

**Question: Should I do something else that I forgotten? If yes, what?
There's a snapd issue with kernel version?**

Comment: Does “modprobe squashfs” return with no error?

Answer (score 1):

https://blogs.gnome.org/hughsie/2019/07/12/gnome-software-in-fedora-will-no-longer-support-snapd/

One of the devs of GNOME stated that they won't be updating snapd in Fedora GNOME distributions anymore. Apparently it's a dated/insecure system.

Hope this helps. I guess if you need it, you could roll back to an earlier supported version.